# testdisk reports an invalid disk size. What is causing this and how to fix it?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, testdisk

I erased by accident the NTFS partition of my archive disk connected on my Ubuntu computer.

As suggested by many online tutorials, I used the program testdisk to recover the erase partition.

Unfortunately, I get the error message that the disk is too small.

```
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63

The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 2000 GB / 1863 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection...

The following partition can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  HPFS - NTFS          121601   1  1 243202   0 63 1953520065


[ Continue ]
NTFS, blocksize=4096, 1000 GB / 931 GiB
```

The command `sudo dmesg | grep blocks` returns the following:

```
[    1.859180] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
```

This is the output of the fdisk command. Sorry for the french. I can't force it into English.

```bsh
$ sudo  fdisk -u=cylinders -l /dev/sda
Disque /dev/sda : 931,51 GiB, 1000204886016 octets, 1953525168 secteurs
Disk model: ST1000LM035-1RK1
Géométrie : 255 têtes, 63 secteurs/piste, 121601 cylindres
Unités : cylindre de 16065 × 512 = 8225280 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 4096 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 4096 octets / 4096 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0xd97bf912
```

Is the NTFS partition corrupted or is the geometry of the disk invalid ?

Could there be a problem with the disk ? How could I check this ? smartctl tells me that everything is OK.

How could I recover the deleted partition ?

Comment: (1) "I erased by accident" – How exactly? What did you do? Did you (partially?) write an image of a 2TB disk to `/dev/sda`? (2) Does the information `1000 GB / 931 GiB` about `/dev/sda` seem correct? Is the disk 1TB? (3) When exactly does TestDisk complain the disk is too small? When it's told to "[Analyze] current partition table"? or "[Quick Search] for partitions"? or "[Deeper Search] for more partitions"? or when?

Comment: In the disk management tool of Ubuntu I simply removed the single partition. The disk has currently no partitions. I never overwrite the data. According to what I have read about it, I only erased the block containing the partition table. The size seam correct. The disk is indeed a 1TB disk. After the quick search has completed. I show the result in my question. It say the disk is too small.

Comment: Prepare a temporary mountpoint like `sudo mkdir -p /mnt/ntfs`. Try `sudo mount -o ro,offset="$((512*2048))" /dev/sda /mnt/ntfs`. Does it succeed? If not, try the same command with `63` instead of `2048`. Does it succeed? If any command succeeds, go to `/mnt/ntfs` and examine the files. Do they look like what you want to recover? Unmount with `sudo umount /mnt/ntfs` and report back. Did any command succeeded? Which one? What was the error (if any)? Please confirm the lost partition was the only one on the disk; no additional partitions. Was the partition (almost) of the size of the disk?

Comment: I have a strange error. `mount: /mnt/ntfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop26, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`. I did copy past your command with /dev/sda and I don’t understand why it refers to loop26. When I do a `sudo fdisk -l` I don’s see /dev/loop26. It ends at /dev/loop25. Changing 2048 to 63 yields the same result.

Comment: Oh well, this was a shot in the dark. I don't know exactly how the disk management tool works, but I expected it had "removed the single partition" by removing the partition table entry. In general one can mount a filesystem without partition entry, if one specifies the right offset. 2048 or 63 logical sectors of 512 bytes are standard offsets I know. OTOH if this was that easy, then probably `testdisk` would have already found the filesystem in a sane place. I may have guessed the offset wrong. Have you tried the Deeper Search?